# Jordan curve theorem for rectifiable curves

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, plane-curves

I am looking for a proof for the Jordan curve theorem in the particular case of rectifiable curves. I consider this case as "intermediate" between the general case and the case of piecewise differentiable (or $C^n$) curves, so I think that, possibly, a proof with "intermediate" difficulty must exist. (A reference for the proof in the case of differentiable curves will be welcomed.)

Comment: This http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8521/nice-proof-of-the-jordan-curve-theorem.

Comment: Any reason you think the rectifiable case is simpler than the general case? The smooth case is indeed easier (but still uses Sard's theorem, which is not completely elementary).

Comment: @MoisheCohen I think that the fact the curve is rectifiable implies that the polygonal approximations are "better" behaved... but anyway, this is just a gut feeling.

Comment: Note that polygonal approximations may (and frequently will) be by non-simple polygonal curves. I do not see how these would help you.

Comment: @MoisheCohen You are right, the hypothesis seems to be of no help.